# Read Input From Command Line

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Trying to use the "read command" to accept user input from the command prompt itself but my script doesnt seem to be moving forward

```
echo "Do you want to continue?(yes/no)"
read -p $1
if [ "$1" == "yes" ]
then
sleep 5s
echo ""
echo " move ahead"
else
    echo ""
    echo "Skipping The Step.."
    echo ""
sleep 5s
fi
```

I want to execute the script like this..

```
sh script.sh yes
sh script.sh no
```

Added a -p to the above script and all seems to work very well. This is my real problem. I have another script test.sh which calls script.sh. So this is how i put the input

```
cat  test.sh yes
#!/bin/bash
echo "execute the below script"
sh script.sh $1



sh test.sh yes
```

This way doesnt work as the script picks up a default no and moves ahead. Any ideas.

Comment: I added a -p command in front of the script and it seems to work. This is my real problem. I have another script called test.sh which in turn calls this script ie script.sh. So in test.sh i added this line.
    cat test.sh yes
    sh script.sh $1
This was it doesnt seem to work

Comment: No, the `-p` argument doesn't even allow the user to change the answer.

Comment: Do you want it as a command line argument or as user input?

Comment: @JuliePelletier - looking at a command line input but only problem is one script has to call the other script like i showed it above.

Comment: `bash` is not `sh`. `bash` is the GNU implementation of a `sh` interpreter, but there are many other different implementations. `read -p` is not valid standard `sh` syntax. Those different `sh` implementations will treat it differently. Check [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/xcu.html) for the `sh` language specification, and specifically for the [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) utility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$1`,`$2` … - command line positional arguments and couldn't be assigned like `read [-p] $1` or any other way except

```
set -- firsr_arg second_arg …
```

For your case it can be test if arguments is present then test them

```
while [ -z "$REPLY" ] ; do
    if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
         read -p "Do you want to continue?(yes/no) "
    else
         REPLY=$1
         set --
    fi
    case $REPLY in
        [Yy]es) sleep 5s
                echo -e "\n move ahead" ;;
         [Nn]o) echo -e "\nSkipping The Step..\n"
                sleep 5s ;;
             *) echo "Wrong answer. Print 'yes' or 'no'" 
                unset REPLY ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: what `set --` does ?

Comment: That is the obvious answer but so far I doubt it will clarify the confusion in OP's mind.

Comment: @Rahul `help set`: `Set or unset values of shell options and positional parameters.    Change the value of shell attributes and positional parameters, or  display the names and values of shell variables.`

Comment: @Costas cool, you have already earned my upvote ;)

Comment: That very much depends on the `sh` implementation. `read 1` or `1=foo` work in `zsh`. `1=foo` also works in `rc` and derivatives. Note that `read -p` is not `sh` syntax. In some `sh` implementations, it's to read from the co-processes. Only the `bash` implementation of `sh` recognises it as the way to specify a prompt. In any case, none of  `read -p var`, `read 1` or `read` without variable is valid POSIX `sh` syntax. You want `printf 'Prompt: '; read REPLY` in a `sh` script.

Comment: @Costas - Ty for the suggestion i was able to alter and figure this out.